# Is it possible to convert Matplotlob plot to blob format without saving the plot to the file?

Tags: python, reactjs, matplotlib, django-rest-framework, blob

As in title. I want to convert plot generated in Matplotlib in Python to blob and then send the blob plot from backend to frontend. Is there any library for that? Or maybe you have any other suggestions how to send the plot to frontend? The thing is I do not want to save the plot to the file. I use Django REST Framework and ReactJS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to send the array/data that realizes the plot to the front-end and use front-end libraries, such as Chart.js and Plotly.js, to plot data on the front-end side.

Nevertheless, if still want to send the Matplotlib image to the front-end, you can convert it to base64 and send the base64 string to the front-end, where you can decode it and display the plot. Here is an example:

```py
import base64
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure()

# it's better to send [1, 2, 3, 4] to front-end and plot it there
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

# here, we covert the plot image to bytes
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)

# send s to front-end and decode it there
s = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I needed. Can you also tell me how to decode base64 string in JS to get a plot?

Comment: @majxla  `var decodedString = atob(encodedString);`